# IValueConverter return int array

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

hi I'm editing a calendar. Now I need to fill the calendar with my favorite days.

That's what I tried and that's the output

```
object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    int[] days = new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31 };
    return days;
}
```

and this is xaml:

```
<ContentPresenter
x:Name="NormalText"
Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource GeorgianToPersianDate}}"
/>
```

[image]

UPDATE:

```
<Style x:Key="CalendarDayButtonStyle" TargetType="CalendarDayButton">

        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="32" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="32" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <local:GeorgianToPersianDate x:Key="GeorgianToPersianDate" />
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle
                            x:Name="TodayBackground"
                            Fill="{DynamicResource DangerBrush}"
                            Opacity="0"
                            RadiusX="16"
                            RadiusY="16" />
                        <Rectangle
                            x:Name="SelectedBackground"
                            Fill="{DynamicResource PrimaryBrush}"
                            Opacity="0"
                            RadiusX="16"
                            RadiusY="16" />
                        <ContentPresenter
                            x:Name="NormalText"
                            Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource GeorgianToPersianDate}}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <TextElement.Foreground>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource PrimaryTextColor}" />
                            </TextElement.Foreground>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To=".35"
                                            Duration="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBackground"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1"
                                            Duration="0:0:.2" />
                                        <ColorAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            To="White"
                                            Duration="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ActiveStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Active" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Inactive">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            To="{DynamicResource ThirdlyTextColor}"
                                            Duration="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DayStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="RegularDay" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Today">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="TodayBackground"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1"
                                            Duration="0" />
                                        <ColorAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            To="White"
                                            Duration="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

this is my xaml i just want to remove dafault days and add my own days i I thought I could do this with the converter. So how can I change the days if I can not do this with the converter?

Comment: `object IValueConverter.Convert` returns `object` object.ToString() - when of type `Int32` - returns the string "Int32".

Comment: @nilsK so how can i fix it? im new in wpf

Comment: Please show the XAML containing this control and look at my answer posted in a moment below.  I can update it once you give more XAML code.

Comment: The ContentPresenter needs a DataTemplate (assigned to its ContentTemplate property) in order to be able to display an array of integers. You have to write the DataTemplate. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII i updated my first post

Comment: @Clemens i dont want to create data template i just want bind a array to content

Comment: Without a ContentTemplate, the ContentPresenter doesn't know how to display the array.

Comment: @Chapache01 I believe I explain somewhat in my answer why you can't simply bind to an array like you're doing.  However; I also explain that using a converter for this is not the correct way to do it.  We will help you get to the right answer but bare with us as we work you through it.  It's best for you to understand why and how than to just tell you.

Comment: @Chapache01 And you may not know either of us but I've seen Clemens on SO quite often.  I feel that he has a great deal to offer in WPF and I've been working WPF since it was released myself.  Hang in there and we'll get you right.

Comment: @Chapache01 I need to see the entire XAML container; not just the ContentPresenter please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First, let's start with the binding.**

A `ContentPresenter` presents it's UI through the `Content` property.  This is just an `object`.  XAML has some fancy ways of translating certain objects to visuals but in the event it fails it just calls `ToString()` on that `object` and displays the text.  Looking at your `IValueConverter` you're returning a `int[]` and the `Content` becomes that.  Why it's not showing `System.Int32[]` is unknown with the code you've given but that's what's happening.

**So knowing that let's look at your `IValueConverter`.**

You're returning an `array` of `int` (`int[]`).  Now that is `System.Int32[]` when you call `ToString()`.

If you're `Template` was a type that contained multiple items like an `ItemsControl` then assigning `ItemsSource` automatically does the same thing but for each item in the array.

Usage of `IValueConverter` is incorrect.  It isn't converting anything and isn't what a converter is used for.  You should just be doing a pure binding to a property in a ViewModel or anywhere but not using `IValueConverter` for this.

A converter is used when you have some binding already; but don't want to use the result of that binding, and would prefer to 'convert' that result to something else.

For example: If you were to bind to a property that returned an `int` value but would prefer to convert that `int` to a related `enum` name; then you would write a converter that reads in the `int` and returns the related `enum` name.

**The fix:**

Hard to give with the XAML you've provided but know that there are several ways to go about this.  First; you need to have at least a template that excepts an array as a binding to display them as they are.  Looking at your image of the view I don't believe this is the case for you.  I believe you're putting the `ContentControl` in a template already; and that template is part of an `ItemsSource` of another control.  If this is the case then you would be binding the `ItemsSource` to the array; and in the `ContentPresenter` just binding to the data that comes to it like so:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="NormalText"
                  Content="{Binding}"/>
```

All that said; I cannot give you a definite solution and in the correct way without seeing the overall XAML.

---

After the update I believe the problem is that you're styling the `CalenderButton` and assigning the `Content` there to the array.  Write the binding as I did above; then custom `Style` the `Calendar` and set the binding there to the array.  I've never done the Calendar style but I can tell by viewing it that the `Calendar` has a `panel` and `ItemsSource` of some fashion and the template of those items is the `CalendarButton`.  In other words the days are distributed to the buttons from the calendar and you're trying to do it directly from the button.

Comment: this is my entire xaml if you can please watch it https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ghost1372/e7bff3738262b9258c421583afc6b568/raw/fbaf8c085612a5862b9abad1d2165eab167c851e/calendar.xaml

Comment: @Chapache01 He is right. Better use an ItemsControl (ItemsPresenter) to display  any kind of collection. This way your converter will work as expected.